# Write an html code to attach a file in mail

Tags: html

I am trying to write an HTML Code which on clicking on one of the links a mail is sent to respective mail Id.But along with that mail i also want to attach an attachment by default.Uptill now i am able to pouplate rest of the fields like to,cc,bcc,sub but the only thing remained is attachment.

Can anyone sort it out for me.Your help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are encoded in mail messages according to the MIME standard.  All the major web scripting languages have modules to read and write MIME messages.  Searching for ["MIME" at CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=mime) for instance will turn up lots of useful Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but you're not going to be able to add an attachment to an email with HTML *only*. You're going to need some server side code.

Are you trying to use mailto: to do this?